# Array structure for breadcrumbs in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display breadcrumbs on my page. My URLs look similar to `domain.com/customer-management/list`. I use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to get these and then I explode them by `/` to get an array.

Currently, I have the following array

```
$paths = array(
    "index.php" => "Home",
    "index.php/customer-management" => "Customer management",
    "index.php/customer-management/list" => "Customer list",
    "index.php/customer-management/new" => "New customer",
    "index.php/account" => "Me",
    "index.php/account/change-password" => "Change password"
);
```

In my code I loop through all the exploded values and get the corresponding text representation from the array.

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($crumbs); $i++) {
    $parts = array();
    for($a = 0; $a <= $i; $a++) {
        $parts[] = $crumbs[$a];
    }

    $path = join("/", $parts);

    echo "<li>" . $paths[$path] . "</li>";
}
```

This works, but when I have a lot of subpages for example for customer management, I have to repeat the `customer-management/` part a lot. How could I turn this into a multidimensional array?

I think this kind of array would be a lot easier to maintain.

```
$paths = array(
    "customer-management" => array(
        "" => "Customer management",
        "list" => "Customer list",
        "new" => "New customer"
    ),
    "account" => array(
        "" => "Me",
        "change-password" => "Change password"
    )
);
```

But, how do I access these keys? How do I recursively loop that?

Comment: So you are asking how to assemble your new array idea so that it mimics your existing array?

Answer (score 0):

This has no error checking for non-existent paths but should get you on the right track:

```
$pathAr = array(
    "customer-management" => array(
        "" => "Customer management",
        "list" => "Customer list",
        "new" => "New customer"
    ),
    "account" => array(
        "" => "Me",
        "change-password" => "Change password"
    )
);

function findTitle($crumbs, $pathAr){

  if(!is_array($crumbs)) $crumbs = explode("/", $crumbs);
  $crumb = array_shift($crumbs);

  if(is_array($pathAr[$crumb])){
    return findTitle($crumbs, $pathAr[$crumb]);
  }else{
    return $pathAr[$crumb];
  }

}

$title = findTitle("customer-management/list", $pathAr);

echo $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take your suggested array, you can restructure it into a new array like this:

```
foreach ($paths AS $path_section => $path_location_array) {

    foreach ($path_location_array AS $path_location_url => $path_location_title) {

        $path_location_key = preg_replace('~//~', '/', 'index.php/'.$path_section.'/'.$path_location_url);

        $new_array[$path_location_key] = $path_location_title;

    }

}
```